# I am trying to get data from time counter OVEN via ModBus RTU protocol, but getting trash in response

Tags: java

I have wrote some simple code to get info from 2 registers of my time counter.
I am sending next command to OVEN:

> 10 03 00 16 00 02 26 8E

and expect to get next response(tryed to do it with OpenSCADA):

> 10 03 04 **00 BF AE B9** 77 04

But instead I am getting this:

> 10 03 04 **00 41 52 47** 77 04

Everything is correct except data-block, even CRC is the same.
Why is that so?

And well, here is a code:

```java
    public static void workFlow(byte[] comm) throws IOException{
        try {
            byte inp [] = new byte [9];
            s = createSocket(address,port);
            s.getOutputStream().write(comm);
            s.setSoTimeout(500);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            s.getInputStream().read(inp);

            for (int i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
                int unsinged = Math.abs(inp[i]);
                System.out.print(" " + Integer.toHexString(unsinged));
            }
            System.out.println("");

            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("init error: " + e.getMessage());
                if (e.getMessage().contains("Read timed out")) {
                    System.out.println("Connection lost. Attempting to reconnect");
                    s.close();
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `int unsinged = Math.abs(inp[i]);`?

It seems like you know that you need an unsigned integer from the bytes but that's not what you're doing; 
You're really just getting the absolute value which isn't what you want.

So use this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(" " + Integer.toHexString(Byte.toUnsignedInt(inp[i])));
}
```

This will avoid the byte being padded with `ff` bytes when it's converted to an integer and make your hex string accurately represent the bytes.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Damn, this is what happens when you try to learn programming by yourself. I was so close and the same time so far )